# ORA 06401 invalid driver designator

Tags: vb.net, oracle, oracle12c

I have a old VB .NET application.
It works with oracle 11 personal edition. 
i move this application in other server with oracle 12 C enterprise edition and the application dont connect herself to DB with the following error code."ORA 06401 invalid driver designator ".

This is the connection string "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Password=xx User Id=yy DataSource=//localhost:1521//zzz extended Properties=;"

Probably is a very trivial mistake but I 've already lost a day

Thanks to all

Gian